# How to prove that in $\{0\} \cup \{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, ...\}, 0$ is not isolated

Tags: real-analysis

(As a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.) I am having trouble proving that $0$ is not an isolated point. If there exists an open ball with radius $\epsilon$ about $0$, I have to find a point of the form $\frac{1}{k}$ within that open ball, but I can't show this. So we have an open ball $\{x : |x| < \epsilon\}$, and I need to show that there exists a point of the form $\frac{1}{k}$ in this set, no matter how small $\epsilon$ is. Suppose there doesn't exist such a point, so that $\frac{1}{k} > \epsilon$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. So then $\frac{1}{\epsilon} > k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, but this doesn't seem to help me since if $\epsilon$ is a tiny $\mathbb{R}$ number, then $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ is some huge number.

Comment: And is there a real number that is so huge that it is greater than every natural number?

Comment: @CarstenS This is where I'm not sure, because if you give me a natural number I can just give you a real number that's $\epsilon$ larger than that natural number, but if you also give me a real number, I can also give you the next highest natural number (by rounding up). So it seems like there isn't an answer to that.

Comment: You just gave the answer! Round $1/\epsilon$ upwards to get your $k$.

Comment: $\frac1{\epsilon}<k$ (not $\frac1{\epsilon}>k$). And if $k$ satisfies then also $m$ with $m\geq k$.

Comment: You not say that for every real number you can find a natural number that is larger. This answers your question: There is no real number that is larger than every natural number. Now if that suffices as a proof in your context or if you have to throw in some magic words like "Archimedean property", I don't know.

Comment: @CarstenS The Archimedean property says that for each real number, there exists a natural number greater than it, but then it's true for each natural number, there exists a real number greater than it (if $k$ is the natural number, then $k+1$ is a real number greater than $k$). So is $1/ \epsilon > k$ true then?

Comment: The statements "There exists a real number $r$ such that for every natural number $n$ we have $r>n$" and "For every natural number $n$ there exists a real number $r$ such that we have $r>n$" are very different. One is true and one is false.

Comment: That's a confusing point. Imagine it's a game: I choose a natural number $n$ and you choose a real number $r$, and you win if $r>n$. The first statement above is the same as, "If you go first you can always win," and the second is "If I go first you can always win."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S := \{ 0 \} \cup \{ \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Then, since $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n$ grows, for every $\delta > 0$ there is some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \delta$ for all $n \geq N$, *i.e.* for every $\delta > 0$ the neighborhood $N(0,\delta)$ contains infinitely many $\frac{1}{n}$, contradicting the definition of isolated point, so $0$ is not isolated in $S$.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how small $\epsilon$ is, there are infinitely many $k$ such that $\frac 1{\epsilon}<k$ so the open interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ for arbitrary $\epsilon$ apply to prove your question.